# Make a rectangular hole on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I wanted to make a tool with tkinter to take a small screenshot with mouse drag and drop. First I want to create a half-transparent canvas on the whole screen. Then when I drag and drop on the screen, the selected part becomes transparent.
How can I make part of the canvas transparent.

Comment: You could use 4 half transparent windows and move them by mouse events in a way that a rectangle becomes *free screen*. Save the coordinates by button press an release to get the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The top left corner of each rectangle is (x0, y0) and the pixel just outside the bottom right corner is (x1, y1)

A rectangle specified by the top left corner (100,100) and bottom right corner (103,103) is a square two pixel by two pixels, which includes pixel (102,102) but does not include (103,103).

rectangles are drawn as two-part:

- on the top and left side of the rectangles, the outline lies inside, while on the bottom and right side it is outside. There is a one-pixel black border by default.
- Imagine a rectangle with 10/10 in the top left corner and 11/11 in the bottom right corner. A blue pixel at (10,10) will be created if you request a no border (width = 0) and fill = "blue" setting. You would get four black pixels from the same options, but if you request a border of one (width = 1 ), then you'd get pixels from (10,10), (10,11) (11,10), and (11,11). The fill is the area within the outline. It appears transparent by default.

Creating a rectangle.

```
id = C.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, option, ...)
```